# Android GraphView Bar chart Multiple series

Tags: android, android-graphview

Hi i have a Bar graph using android GraphView. have 3 series that i need to pass into it but its currently drawing all 3 series onto of each other is there a way to change the width of the bar so that it shows

heres what i have sofar

```
try{
                    JSONArray graphArray = returnGraphyArray(statistics);
                    if(graphArray != null){
                        int graphLength = graphArray.length();
                        GraphViewData[] calls = new GraphViewData[graphLength];
                        GraphViewData[] length = new GraphViewData[graphLength];
                        GraphViewData[] transfered = new GraphViewData[graphLength];

                        for(int r = 0; r < graphLength; r++){
                            JSONObject row = graphArray.getJSONObject(r);
                            calls[r] = new GraphViewData(r,Integer.parseInt(row.getJSONObject("data").getString("total_calls")));
                            length[r] = new GraphViewData(r,Integer.parseInt(row.getJSONObject("data").getString("avg_call_length"))/60);
                            transfered[r] = new GraphViewData(r,Integer.parseInt(row.getJSONObject("data").getString("calls_transferred")));
                        } 

                        GraphViewSeries totalCallsSeries = new GraphViewSeries( "Total Calls", new GraphViewSeriesStyle(getResources().getColor(R.color.pink), 5),calls);
                        GraphViewSeries totalCallLengthSeries = new GraphViewSeries( "Total Call Length", new GraphViewSeriesStyle(getResources().getColor(R.color.green), 5),length);
                        GraphViewSeries totalCallsTransSeries = new GraphViewSeries( "Calls Transfered", new GraphViewSeriesStyle(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), 5),transfered);

                        BarGraphView graphView = new BarGraphView(context, "");
                        graphView.addSeries(totalCallLengthSeries); 
                        graphView.addSeries(totalCallsTransSeries); 
                        graphView.addSeries(totalCallsSeries); // data
                        graphView.setHorizontalLabels(bottomlabels);
                        graphView.setShowLegend(false);
                        graphView.setLegendAlign(LegendAlign.TOP);
                        graphView.setLegendWidth(SM_Global.pxFromDp(context, 100));
                        graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setNumHorizontalLabels(6);
                        layout.addView(graphView);  
                    }else{
                        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ImageView legend = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.graph_legend);
                        legend.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
```

Comment: Yes, GraphView 4.0 can only handle one bar series

Answer (score 0):

According to the GraphView website:
"Note: It is currently not possible to plot multiple bar charts. To say it more in detail: It is possible, but the bars will be rendered at the same position and so they will be overlapped."

I would suggest using AChartEngine instead. Here's the link to the jar file 
https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list

and here's an example
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-bar-chart-using-achartengine/